# How can I load some ActiveRecord models from a YAML file and save them to the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, yaml

I'm trying to save some lookup table data out to a YAML file so that later when I need to set up my app on a different machine I can load the data in as seed data.

The data is stuff like select options, and it's pretty much set, so no worries about the live data changing between serializing and deserializing.

I have output the data like this...

```
file = File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/tasks/questions/questions.yml", 'w')
questions = Question.find(:all, :order => 'order_position')
file << YAML::dump(questions)
file.close()
```

And I can load the file like this...

```
questions = YAML.load_file('lib/tasks/questions/questions.yml')
```

However, when I try to save a question I get this error...

```
>> questions[0].save
NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for #<YAML::Object:0x2226b84>
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried your scenario and I did not have any issues. I did the following changes to your YAML file creation logic:

```
yml_file = Rails.root.join('lib', 'tasks', 'questions', 'questions.yml')
File.open(yml_file, 'w') do |file|
  questions = Question.order(:order_position).to_a
  YAML::dump(questions, file)
end
```

I was able to retrieve the `questions` list as follows:

```
yml_file = Rails.root.join('lib', 'tasks', 'questions', 'questions.yml')
question_attributes_list = YAML.load_file(yml_file).map(&:attributes)
questions = Question.create(question_attributes_list)
```

Answer (score 21):

Create a `seed.yml` file in `db` directory. Add a YAML document for each model you want to create. This document should contain a list of hash. Each hash should contain model attributes.

```
  users:
      -   login: jake
          password: jake123
          password_confirmation: jake123
          first_name: Jake
          last_name: Driver

      -   login: Jane
          password: jane123
          password_confirmation: jane123
          first_name: Jane
          last_name: McCain

  categories:

  products:
```

In your seed.rb file

```
seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seed.yml')
config = YAML::load_file(seed_file)
User.create(config["users"])
Category.create(config["categories"])
Product.create(config["products"])
```

Run the rake task to load the rows

```
rake db:seed
```

Comment: Man, this is so useful to know. Thank you. Is it still relevant in Rails 4?

Comment: @Batman I thinks so. This relies on standard YAML parser and AR array create method.

Answer (score 11):

Does the accepted answer actually answer the question?  It looks like the asker wanted to save the models, not just retrieve them from a YAML file.

To actually *save* the loaded model(s) back to the database you need to fool `ActiveRecord` into thinking the model needs saving.  You can do it with this rather dirty bit of code

```
questions = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/tasks/questions/questions.yml")
questions.each{|q| q.instance_variable_set("@new_record", true); q.save}
```

It works and saved my bacon once or twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails 2.3.4 (or above), they have a `seeds.rb` file that can be found in your applications `db` folder.  This lets you define basic active record creates, and when you've set up your new project, you can simply call:

```
rake db:seed
```

There is an excellent [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) on it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data), and a good blog post about it [here](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2009/09/05/planting-the-seeds).  If you're not using Rails 2.3.4 (Or, ideally, 2.3.5), I highly recommend updating for these cool features, and addition security/bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is a great feature. I want to store the data in a YAML file and load it using `seeds.rb`. There is enough data that hard-coding the model instantiations directly in `seeds.rb` would be awkward.

Comment: seeds.rb is just a ruby file.  You can load YAML inside of seeds.rb as described here (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/YAML.html), and simply loop through the array(s) while doing a Model.create().