# How to export a nested ActiveRecord record to a document that can be reimported to update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activerecord

I'm trying to turn a database record into an exportable document, such that I can reimport it and update the database. I'd just use CSV but it's also nested, say *Country* `has_many` *Provinces* `has_many` *Cities*.

I've tried dumping YAML per [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339021/how-can-i-load-some-activerecord-models-from-a-yaml-file-and-save-them-to-the-db):

```
File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/tasks/canada.yml", 'w') do |file|
  country = Country.find(1)
  country.provinces
  country.cities
  YAML::dump(country, file)
end
```

But when I load, it doesn't:

```
country = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/tasks/canada.yml")
```

I even tried hacking the `new_record` flag per [this article](http://blog.zerosum.org/2008/2/20/activerecord-importing-yaml) but it doesn't change anything. I'm using Rails 3.x.

This must be something other people have done before. How? Or do I need to approach the problem differently?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that `country.save` will not produce a new record in the database? You can try `Country.create!(country.serializable_hash)`. That will at least create a new record based on the attributes of `country`. The country id will be changed and I guess nested objects (Province, City) will not be handled properly.

Comment: The point of the question is to do this for an object with nested objects, right? I don't believe this solution applies.