# How to turn Yaml file entires into models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, yaml

I want to create a landing page for internal apps that updates itself so I have a gem in place that polls the file where apps are stored each night and then spits out a yaml file with the latest information.

Here is what the yaml file looks like:

```
Applications:
  App1:
    Name: name1
    Link: link1
  App2
    Name: name2
    Link: link2
```

I want to sort through the yaml file and create a `model` for each 'app' entry that I can manipulate but I have no idea how I could do that or where to place that logic.  I think it may go in the seed.rb file but then would I have to run `rake db:seed` each time someone visited the page?

Comment: Possible dupplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2339810/163203

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I load some ActiveRecord models from a YAML file and save them to the DB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339021/how-can-i-load-some-activerecord-models-from-a-yaml-file-and-save-them-to-the-db)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write:

```
require 'yaml'

data = YAML.load_file 'filename.yml'

data['Applications'].each do |key, values|
  Application.create values
end
```